# webstorm ignoring 'excluded' directories in a .tsconfig.json file

Tags: typescript, webstorm

When trying to compile typescript files in webstorm, I am bombarded with compilation errors that originate from files in the `node_modules` folder.

My .tsconfig looks like

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

and I have 'use .tsconfig.json' checked in `preferences > typescript`.

The errors I'm getting are from the 'reflect-metadata/Reflect' package

```
TS2304: Cannot find name 'msCrypto'
```

Comment: works for me (WebStorm 11.0.2). I'd suggest creating a support ticket, providing the project that shows up the issue to support

Comment: here the same problem. WebStorm 2016.1 (WS-145.258)

Comment: You may want to double check the file name, you keep saying `.tsconfig.json` when I've always thought it should just be `tsconfig.json` (no leading dot).

Answer (score 1):

update to 2016.1.1 and activate tsconfig.json in the settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to change

```
"exclude": [
    "node_modules"
]
```

to

```
"exclude": [
        "./node_modules"
]
```

I am using

[image: WebStorm version]