# WebStorm ignoring exclude option in tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-rider

How do I set a directory as excluded from TypeScript compilation in WebStorm?

The IDE's TypeScript compilation service doesn't seem to be respecting the `tsconfig.json`'s `exclude` setting for compilation. Running `tsc` from the terminal properly ignores the needed folder, but WebStorm (and for that matter all JetBrains IDEs) completely ignore it and compile everything in the root directory.

I have set `-p ./tsconfig.json` as an option in `Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Typescript` and yet the excluded directory still gets compiled.

Comment: Hey, have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34224972/webstorm-ignoring-excluded-directories-in-a-tsconfig-json-file
Might be related to paths diff...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. We use monorepo and recently migrated to project references. There was a base `tsconfig.json` in the project root, all the other project used typescript project references and extended the base `tsconfig.json` accordingly. When compiled any project with `tsc -b` everything was ok. But WebStorm picked up the root `tsconfig.json` where `exclude` was empty, so tried to compile everything. Maybe it is the same for your setup, worth a check.